# Projective variety of general type such that $S^m \Omega_X^1$ is globally generated

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety *of general type*; in my applications, I work with a surface, but let me ask this question in full generality.

Assume that for some $m \geq 1$ the vector bundle $S^m \Omega_X^1$ is generated by global sections, namely, the evaluation map  $$H^0(X, \, S^m \Omega_X^1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to S^m \Omega^1_X$$ is surjective.

> **Question.** Is it true that $K_X$ is ample? Otherwise, what is a counterexample?

I started working on these topics rather recently, so I apologize if this question turns out to be trivial for the experts. Any answer and/or reference to the relevant literature will be highly appreciated.

**Edit** (12/26/2021). Follow-up question about the base-point freeness of $|K_X|$ asked as [MO412382](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412382/projective-variety-of-general-type-such-that-sm-omega-x1-is-globally-genera).

Comment: Is the variety smooth?  If so, then you at least have that the canonical divisor class is nef.

Comment: @JasonStarr: oh yes, it is. I will edit the question, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is a surface it is true. In general, a smooth projective variety with $S^m\Omega ^1_X$  globally generated does not contain any smooth rational curve $C$. Indeed $\Omega ^1_C$ is a quotient of $\Omega ^1_X$, so  $S^m\Omega ^1_C$ is also globally generated, which of course implies $g(C)\geq 1$.

Now if $X$ is a surface, this implies that $K_X$ is ample (in fact $K_X$ is ample if and only if $X$ does not contain any smooth rational curve with square $\,-1$ or $-2$).

**Edit:** As pointed out by YangMills in the comments, the result holds in all dimensions: if a smooth projective variety $X$ of general type contains no smooth rational curve, $K_X$ is ample — see Lemma 2.1 in [arxiv.1606.01381](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01381.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it also true that $|K_X|$ is base-point free (assuming $\dim 
 X=2$)?

Comment: I don't think so (if $m\geq 2$ of course), but I don't have an example at hand.

Comment: In any dimension if $X$ is smooth with $K_X$ is nef and big and $X$ contains no rational curve, then $K_X$ is ample, see e.g. Lemma 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01381

Comment: so combining my comment with the answer of abx and the comment by Jason gives you an affirmative answer in all dimensions

Comment: @YangMills: Nice, thank you! I have edited my answer to make it complete.

Comment: @YangMills: this is very nice, thank you!

Comment: @abx: thanks for your comment. Maybe I will ask the problem about the base-point freeness of $|K_X|$ as a separate question.