# Projective variety of general type such that $S^m \Omega_X^1$ is globally generated - Part II

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This is a follow-up to my previous question [MO412306](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412306/projective-variety-of-general-type-such-that-sm-omega-x1-is-globally-genera/).

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective surface *of general type* (this is the case I am mostly interested in, but one could ask the question in every dimension) and assume that for some $m \geq 1$ the vector bundle $S^m \Omega_X^1$ is generated by global sections, namely, the evaluation map  $$H^0(X, \, S^m \Omega_X^1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to S^m \Omega^1_X$$ is surjective.

The nice answer to the aforementioned question shows that in this situation $K_X$ is ample, essentially because our assumption on $\Omega^1_X$ implies that $X$ does not contain any smooth rational curve. So, let me now ask the following

> **Question.** Is $|K_X|$ base-point free? If not, what is a counterexample?

**Remark.** The answer is *yes* when $m=1$. In fact, if $\Omega_X$ is globally generated then, for every $x \in X$, we can find two global sections $a, \, b \in H^0(X, \, \Omega_X^1)$ such that $a(x), \, b(x)$ generate the fibre $\Omega^1_{X, \, x}$. Thus $a(x) \wedge b(x)$ generate $\wedge^2 \Omega^1_{X, \, x}=\omega_{X, \, x}$, namely, $a \wedge b$ is a global section of $K_X$ that does not vanish at $x$.